# XML parsing and treeview

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xml, treeview

parse the xml file:

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(fileName);
while (reader.Read())
{
    switch (reader.NodeType)
    {
        case XmlNodeType.Element: // The node is an element.
            Console.Write("<" + reader.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(">");
            break;
        case XmlNodeType.Text: //Display the text in each element.
            Console.WriteLine(reader.Value);
            break;
        case XmlNodeType.EndElement: //Display the end of the element.
            Console.Write("</" + reader.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(">");
            break;
    }
}
```

How do i now enter nodes to get a tree view of the xml file i'm parsing? This is what i have thus far:

```
<TreeView Margin="177,61" Name="myTreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=XmlNodeType.Element}" >
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=XmlNodeType.Element}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=XmlNodeType.Text}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

but nothing shows up.... just don't understand how to add nodes i guess...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the nodes in code behind like that:

```
var newNode = new TreeViewItem
{
    Header = "New Node"
};
myTreeView.Items.Add(newNode);
```

This adds a node to the top of the tree. If you want to build a hierarchy you have to add the node at the appropiate position like that:

```
// Find the node you want to have as parent.
var parentNode = myTreeView.Items.Cast<TreeViewItem>().FirstOrDefault(item => item.Header = "Parent Node");
if (parentNode != null)
{
    var newNode = new TreeViewItem
    {
        Header = "New Node"
    };
    parentNode.Items.Add(newNode);
}
```

BTW: I would use to `x:Name` Property to name the elements in Xaml, sometimes there is some trouble in code behind when you use only `Name`

Comment: Wow, this is so cool! Thanks for the help. Voted you up and selected your answer

Comment: hmmm seems to be a problem with this portion when creating a hierarchy "item.Header = "Parent Node")" Also, i don't think i quite understand that line. Would you be able to explain it to me?

Comment: That was only a sample to find a parent node. When you "walk" through your xml file and you've added a node, then you already have that parent node for all child nodes. The line I posted, do the following (as a sample!): It takes the all Items, cast them to TreeViewItem and searches the first node, that "Parent Node" set as header.